# vb.net code for marking the attendance using datagrid view

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am doing a project on the topic student attendance management system.I have no idea about how to mark the attendance.Can I use the datagrid view for marking the attendance of students.I put a check box in one cell of the datagrid of marking the attendance.How can I store the value of the check box from the datagrid to the database
Here is my code.Please help me..

```
Private Sub attendance_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=sa;database=stud"
        mysqlconn.Open()
        'MsgBox("connection is ok")'

        'Dim squery1 As Array()'
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Dim sql As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from student where branch='" & teacher_login.com_dept.Text & "' and semester='" & teacher_login.com_sem.Text & "'", mysqlconn)

        Dim ds = New DataSet

        sql.Fill(ds, "view")
        If (ds.Tables("view").Rows.Count > 0) Then

            For i = 0 To ds.Tables("view").Rows.Count - 1
                count = ds.Tables("view").Rows.Count - 1
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)

                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = Trim(ds.Tables("view").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
                Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
                chk.HeaderText = "Present/Absent"
                chk.Name = "chk"
                If TypeOf Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
                    Dim dgvCheckBoxCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6)
                    'Commit the data to the datasouce.'
                    Me.DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)

                    Dim checked As Boolean = CType(dgvCheckBoxCell.Value, Boolean)
                    'MsgBox(checked)'

                    MsgBox("ok")
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

code for save button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To count
        If chk.CheckState Then
            MsgBox("ok")
            Dim sql As String = "Insert into attendance values ('" & teacher_login.com_sem.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_dept.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.Dat_day.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_hour.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_tsub.Text & "','" & "present" & "')"
            Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlconn)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Else
            Dim sql As String = "Insert into attendance values ('" & teacher_login.com_sem.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_dept.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.Dat_day.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_hour.Text.Trim & "','" & teacher_login.com_tsub.Text & "','" & "Absent" & "')"
            Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlconn)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In your save event you need to loop through the datagridview and get that value, currently you are not. Also look into the using statement with parameters.

Comment: You are doing way too much work. Databinding is your friend. Have a look at [this sample](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/)